# Как удалить ошибку npm

Tags: linux, archlinux

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/.travis.yml exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/LICENSE exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/README.md exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/defaults.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/index.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/.bin/network-address exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/inherits/LICENSE exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/inherits/README.md exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/inherits/inherits.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/inherits/inherits_browser.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/inherits/package.json exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/README.md exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/index.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/package.json exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/tests/index.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/tests/test-match-negative.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/tests/test-match-positive.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/tests/test-match-strict.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/tests/test-match.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/murl/tests/test-replace.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/network-address/README.md exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/network-address/cli.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/network-address/index.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/network-address/package.json exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/README.md exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/example.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/index.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/package.json exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/index.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/test-connect-compatible.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/test-double-mixin.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/test-getters-and-setters.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/test-no-leaks.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/test-prototypical.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/test-simple-request.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/node_modules/protein/tests/test-simple-response.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/package.json exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/index.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-body-parsers.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-errors.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-flow-control.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-fork.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-match.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-matches.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-multi-listen.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-plugins.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-random-port-cluster.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-random-port.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-rewrite.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-route-app.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-route.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-routes.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-sub-app-route.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
/usr/lib/node_modules/root/tests/test-urls.js exists in both 'brosec' and 'padoracle'
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded
```

Comment: Лучше уж краш с ошибкой, чем без неё) не надо тут ошибки удалять)

Comment: Что такое brosec и что такое padoracle? Ни в официальных репозиториях, ни в AUR таких пакетов не существует